# App Android sin Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

¿Que tipo de app sería una que desde su inicio o ejecución trabaja sin interfaz gráfica propia y solo lo hace usando intents de los recursos como la camára?
¿Llega a considerarse un Service, teniendo en cuenta que la App requiere de la intervención del usuario a lo largo de su ejecución?.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes revisar la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html?hl=es) "Un Service es un componente que realiza operaciones en segundo plano sin una interfaz de usuario"

Comment: Gracias por responder. Has dado en el foco de mi duda. La app que quiero hacer no tiene interfaz de usuario. Pero a su vez no se puede decir que realice operaciones en segundo plano. Porque requiere la intervención del usuario medient intents de los recursos habituales y si cancela se detiene el programa